# Eclipse Marketplace plugin says it can be installed by drag-and-drop - but it can't

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm running Eclipse 2019-09 on a remote machine via an X server. Now, in a browser, I'm looking at this page:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/opencl-development-tool#group-details

It's an Eclipse plugin. There's an Install button - which tells me I should drag it to my Eclipse workspace. Ok, fine, I can do that... except - when I do drag it there, nothing happens, and I'm at a loss regarding How I'm supposed to install this plugin.

Notes:

- My Eclipse has an "Eclipse Marketplace Client" available from the help menu.
- I'm running Windows 10 locally, the remote machine is SLES 15 but with Eclipse 2019-09 installed manually.

Comment: Do you have the Marketplace Client installed? You'll see an option to launch it from the Help menu if so. If not, that's why this process is not working.

Comment: @nitind: Yes, see edit.

Comment: Ahh, it doesn't declare itself as compatible with that release.

Comment: @nitind: I see... too bad there's no error message. Can I try to force compatibility, and see it manages after all? Or does it not work like that?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You could go to the underlying Update Site shown in the entry details at https://www.eclipse.org/setups/marketplace/?id=2235823 , but...the site is not resolving for me at all. You might have to go to its sources at https://bitbucket.org/account/user/ngmsopencl/projects/PROJ and export it yourself as a deployable ir oder to install it.

Comment: @nitind: Would you mind explaining how to do that, as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60829923/1593077)?

Comment: Done, with a link to the original doc.