# How do I "export" this Eclipse plugin from sources?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'd like to use this Eclipse plugin:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/opencl-development-tool#group-details

with my Eclipse 2019-09. But - there's a version incompatibility, or so I'm told. It's been suggested to me that I might be able to use the [plugin sources](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/) to "export it yourself as a deployable in order to install it".

But it's not at all clear to me how I'm supposed to do that. I'm not fluent with building Java artifacts nor with Eclipse plugin development and deployment. At the link above, there are several repositores, and most of them are only two or three files, one of them being `pom.xml`. Only one seems like a proper repo ([this one](https://bitbucket.org/ngmsopencl/hu.ngms.opencl.editor/src/master/)).

What do I do with these repos and how can I make a plugin I can install in Eclipse, using them?

Comment: This is using maven with [tag:tycho], but it isn't following the recommended layout (see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)). 'hu.ngms.opencl.aggregator' looks the main pom. But the build is referencing old versions of Eclipse and will need updating and may well need errors fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's become simpler over time--there's a wizard with options for doing this *once you've got the plug-in in your workspace compiling cleanly*. Install the Plug-in Development Environment for your version of Eclipse. It should be in an update site already in your list of Available Software Sites (that's a preference page). Then, follow the steps of the **Export and Install into the Running Host** task in the built-in Help. The first 3 sentences of that task refer to the normal process of debugging plug-ins from source projects in the workspace. The rest of it is a guide to exactly what needs to be done here.

Here's the link to the 2020-03 version of that documentation:
https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/ui_export_install_into_host.htm?cp=4_2_4_0

And the relevant parts:

> ...it is sometimes necessary for code to be tested in your host, your currently running Eclipse instance. To test code in the host, you need to export and install into the running Eclipse instance.
>
> To export plug-ins and features and install them into the host Eclipse do the following:

1. Develop your plug-ins and features in the workspace
2. Open the export wizard, either Open the plug-in export wizard **File** > **Export...** > **Plug-in Development** > **Deployable plug-ins and fragments** or Open the feature export wizard **File** > **Export...** > **Plug-in Development** > **Deployable features**
3. Select your plug-ins or features to export and install
4. Select the last option on the Destination tab **Install into host. Repository**. Then choose a directory to create the repository in
5. Hit **Finish**. The export operation will run followed by the installation operation.
6. If the operations completed successfully, you will be prompted to restart. Choose to restart now
7. our plug-ins will be installed and running after the restart. You can see what has been installed using the **Installation Details** button on the **About** Dialog (available by going to **Help** > **About Eclipse SDK**)